# Source subdirectories in Swift package

Tags: swift

In a library package, I would like to move some source files from the "Sources" folder to subdirectories, without changing language semantics (module name, visibility, etc).

Now I have a layout like:

```
LibraryProject
  Sources
    AnotherThing.swift
    FooProtocol.swift
    SomeFoo.swift
    OtherFoo.swift
    BarProtocol.swift
    SomeBar.swift
    OtherBar.swift
```

And, if I change it to something like:

```
LibraryProject
  Sources
    AnotherThing.swift
    Foo
      FooProtocol.swift
      SomeFoo.swift
      OtherFoo.swift
    Bar
      BarProtocol.swift
      SomeBar.swift
      OtherBar.swift
```

Then, invoking `swift build` fails:

> error: the package has an unsupported layout, unexpected source file(s) found: [...]

Is this layout possible? I only found this issue https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-66 that suggests that it is not, but I cant find confirmation (or reason) in the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I have found two options that work for Swift projects on Linux, either all `.swift` files must be directly in the `Sources` folder, or there must be one subfolder in `Sources` and as many subfolders within that as you like.

Swift builds a Module out of the top-level subfolder in `Sources` and includes all the subfolders within that.

I don't believe it is possible to have two Modules within the same `Sources` folder, as a Module would not recognise any code outside itself.

So in your example a working structure would be:

```
LibraryProject
  Sources
    YourModuleName
      AnotherThing.swift
      Foo
        FooProtocol.swift
        SomeFoo.swift
        OtherFoo.swift
      Bar
        BarProtocol.swift
        SomeBar.swift
        OtherBar.swift
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the Folder structure for Swift package**
*And Here i have mentioned how to add the resources and add lines in Package*
[image]

Comment: Code in screenshots is really not helpful. Would be much better to provide the searchable text in the answer too.

Comment: Agreed, please amend your answer with the actual Package.swift file.